# odd R error when using read.table to read a file

Tags: r

```
Coverage_data <- read.table("/home/ning/coverage.txt", header=FALSE,sep="\t",
                                         na.strings="NA",dec=".",strip.white=TRUE)
```

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     too many items

The R code I used is aboved.
coverage.txt is 49Gb and it looks like this:

```
$ head coverage.txt
chr1    1   0
chr1    2   0
chr1    3   0
chr1    4   0
chr1    5   0
chr1    6   0
chr1    7   0
chr1    8   0
chr1    9   0
chr1    10  0
```

Did this error occur to anyone?

Comment: Unless you have 49 Gb of memory (more, really), you're going to have to break the job into chunks.

Comment: @alistaire yes I think I had enough memory

Comment: You can use `rxImport` from `RevoScaleR` and output is a `.xdf` format (if you have the resources)

Comment: @LucasLau It's possible, but that would be a very expensive computer.

Comment: It's quite possible to require more memory inside R than in the input file. Numeric class items need 8 bytes, so a single byte value of `1` may expand to ten times that size when imported. Saying "I think I had enough memory" leaves many questions unanswered. Do you really have 1024 GB of Ram???

Comment: @42- well that I don't. Yeah now I am thinking it might be the ram problem. I am gonna break the data into chromosome and then run it again. Thx guys!